# Why runnung mvn clean install command (on a Spring Boot project) I obtain unit test failure also if I commented out these methods to skip tests?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, junit

I am not working with Spring\Spring Boot from several years and I am starting a project with this technology so I have some doubts.

I am working on a simple project retrieved from GIT and starting working on it implementing my functionality. It works fine but I have the following doubts.

From command line (into the root directory of my project) I compile it using the command:

```
mvn clean install
```

in order to delete the previous version of my application and then compile, test & package again my application.

Then I start my application by this command:

```
mvn spring-boot:run
```

And the application correctly starts:

It starts without problem. My doubt is in the previous phase when I perform the **mvn clean install** command. It performs also the unit tests defined inside the project but all test failed. And here the strange behavior.

I obtain exception like this:

```
Running com.springboot.excelapi.integration.ExcelResourceUnitTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.001 sec <<< FAILURE! - in com.springboot.excelapi.integration.ExcelResourceUnitTest
initializationError(com.springboot.excelapi.integration.ExcelResourceUnitTest)  Time elapsed: 0 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.Exception: No runnable methods
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.validateInstanceMethods(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.collectInitializationErrors(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:128)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.validate(ParentRunner.java:416)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.<init>(ParentRunner.java:84)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:65)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:138)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner.<init>(SpringRunner.java:49)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
        at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)
        at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
        at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
        at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
        at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
        at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:33)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:283)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:173)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:203)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:155)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)
```

and at the end of the Maven install phase I have the following summary that says that all the tests are failed:

```
Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 2, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  11.251 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-02-16T19:24:02+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test (default-test) on project excel-api: There are test failures.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Please refer to C:\Users\nobil\Documents\workspace-sts-3.9.11.RELEASE\spring-boot-excel-api-master.zip_expanded\spring-boot-excel-api-master\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

The strange thing is that I commented out all the test methods into my JUnit classes. For example the previous error is related to this test class:

```
package com.springboot.excelapi.integration;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.web.WebAppConfiguration;

import com.springboot.excelapi.Application;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = { Application.class })
@WebAppConfiguration
@ActiveProfiles(profiles = { "no-liquibase" })
public class ExcelResourceUnitTest {

    /*
    @Test
    public void processCompVibrAndTempoExcelTabTest()
    {
        final ExcelService excelService = new ExcelService();

        try {
            excelService.processCompVibrAndTempExcelTab();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    */


}
```

as you can see this class contains a single test method that is commented out.

So why when I perform the **mvn clean install** command it seems that it is trying to execute test method that at the moment are disabled by commenting out it?

Comment: As to the tests failing: I am unsure while the test is executed even when they are commented out. Did you save the changes? But the tests should not be failing in the first place. I would recommend contacting the developer and ask for advice. Remark: you can deactivate tests by e.g. executing `mvn -DskipTests clean install`.

Comment: @Turing85 obviously I saved the code before run the mvn clean install again

Comment: Comment to annotations and try again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don’t want to run the test use `@Ignore` on class or single test method.

It seems that there are still tests that run (4 tests as maven summarizes)
so all-in-all probably you shouldn’t always run `mvn -DskipTests clean install` or at least not always run it because you’ll still want the working tests to run.

Now as for the error, you should have at least one public method annotated with `@Test` so leave the method but comment out its content (again, IMO its better to use `@Ignore` as I’ve said before)